# Running too many appliances needing water on a well system and now no water

Tags: plumbing, well-pump, well

My wife did 2 dishwasher loads, a washer load on high, and then took a shower....all of this in about a  time frame of 3 hours. Water comes out slow and weak out of the faucets in the basement and first floor and a trickle from the 2nd floor. I checked the welltron at that time and the psi gauge read 0.  Now, 12 hours later, it reads 15psi. Help!!!

Comment: Have you checked the breaker and if your well has a safety controller for running dry? On most of the safety controllers I have worked on there is a Manuel reset to protect the pump when it runs dry some require a power cycle at the breaker box to reset. These would be my first 2 checks.

Comment: How long have you been using this well system?  What kind of well system is it?  Do you have a submersible well pump?  Does the well have a flow rating (if so, what)?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly possible to run a well down in level to the point where it is effectively dry. Water is not an endless resource.

As you pump water out of the well casing the level in the casing drops. Depending on the depth of your well, the height of the water table, and the capacity of your well you can pump the casing dry.

Then, water refills the well casing over time and now you have water again. If you are in an area that has experienced low rainfall, overpumping from agriculture or other issues your water level couldn't be extremely low already.

Another issue could be a clogged screen on your pump. Only a well service could help you with this.

Try moderating your water usage and see if that helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the bladder in the pressure tank is older, it may be getting too weak to reinflate on its own. Rust, iron and other deposits can also weigh heavy on the bladder causing it to weaken.

Comment: Bladders contain the air charge they can rupture and lose pressure but a waterlogged tank would cause rapid cycling of the pump but with faucets open they would run

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's not the bladder's strength which pushes the water in and out; it's the pressure of the air behind the bladder.